# how to completely redirect all requests for one domain to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, redirect, url-rewriting, dns

I have a .net mvc3 website hosted on godaddy (Deluxe 4GH plan) with an SSL and a dedicated IP address (173.201.*.*） recently ,I noticed that there is a strange domain (let's say www.strange-domain.com) **which is also pointing to my dedicated IP address** (173.201.*.*）.that is ,besides my own domain (say ,www.my-domain.com), this new strange domain can also access every part of my site (my application) including the admin area! I really do not want this kind of thing to happen because for the point of SEO ,the search engine  may think that two domains pointing to the same site is a kind of cheating.

So I contacted godaddy ,they said that they can not do anything to prevent someone from pointing  his own domain to my dedicated IP address.I think it's true ,yes ,it's up to the domain owner.
Now ,I need to implement one mechanism that can redirects all the requests of that strange domain to my own domain without the visitors know it . that is : if a visitor is requesting 
**www.strange-domain.com/some/path/to/page** ,then he will be redirected to **www.my-domain.com/some/path/to/page**  well if this can not be done ,the at least the visitor should be redirected to my domain's home page :**www.strange-domain.com**

I know that this maybe done with the IIS url rewriting .I tried but failed.I really not good at doing this. so may be you can help me by give me a detail implementation of this ?

also ,since my site is powered by .NET MVC3, if the url rewriting does not work ,I want to know  if I can do it with some .NET MVC3 features ,such as the routing system,Global.asax .... if both can achieve this ,which one is preferred ,and why :)   so many questions , thank you all in advance!:)

**update1:**
now ,I have the following rewrite rules.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirects to www.my-domain.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.my-domain.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.my-domain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

I think it is taking affect now ,since both the requests for my-domain.com(with out www prefix ) and strange-domain.com (also without wwww) are now getting the folowing error:

[image]
can you please give me any other ideas? thank you !

Comment: If you're not in control of the other domain name and you're worried about it, it would be better to return a 404 for all requests coming in through said domain, imho. And, if somebody is pointing their domain name to your servers, why are you worried about what Google thinks? Security should be your first concern.

Comment: yes ,I knew that .I just want to know solutions for this security hole... can you please give me some advice ?

Comment: Make sure you're configuring your host headers properly. See [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=WS.10).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it would be preferable to use IIS URL rewriting, rather than anything in MVC3 because the URL rewrite engine in IIS handles the requests before they reach ASP.NET.

Static assets, like images, javascript files and stylesheets may not always be served from within ASP.NET and any URL redirection within ASP.NET would not work.

To globally redirect all requests that do not match your desired server URL see [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/30/iis-url-rewrite-redirect-multiple-domain-names-to-one.aspx)

Essentially, you want to configure a **condition** where {HTTP_HOST} **does not** match the pattern ^www.my-domain.com$

The config that results should look like this:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirects to www.my-domain.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mydomain.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.my-domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

### In Addition

When you say that the other domain can access all areas of your site including your admin area, surely you mean they can just see the authorization page, not that they bypass your authorization - in which case you need to take a serious look at your security.

In essence, you're not going to be able to stop someone pointing a domain at your IP address, so you need to think about how your application handles that.

Comment: asafb,thanks for the ansower.but I just your xml code into my web.config (replaced with my real domain of course). but nothing seems changed. when request the strange domain , I did not redirected to my realy domain. do you have any idieas  ? thank you..

Comment: also I noticed that ,if I just paste your xml code under <system.webServer> ,then nothing will happen as I did not touch the web.config   .but if I remove the  <globalRules> element between <rewrite>  and <rules>elements ,then I will get a 500 server error from godaddy.

Comment: +1 for "In Addition."  I would also add that using Host Headers is a step in the right direction--though it doesn't save you if "including the admin area" means access without proper authorization...

Comment: Have edited the config sample, changing globalRules to rules. Turns out that globalRules need to appear in your global webserver config. Pasting the above code into your local web.config (at the root site, not within a sub-application) will allow the rules to work

Comment: thanks asafb. I actually did what you said a moment ago(change the globalrules to rules).But now there is another problem.before the url rewriting,I can access my site with or without the www prefix of the domain. but now after the rewriting,I can only access my site with the www.my-domain.com ,both the my-domain.com and strange-domain.com can not get access.I tried to add another rule that add a www prefix to the domain.but it is failed.I keep getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error.I found the rule on stack overflow so I guess the rule is Ok. any suggestions ?

Comment: I am now googling ,I see that many people are failed to get the iis url rewrite work on godaddy's server.I guess I am one of them. here is my Stack Trace: 
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Web.MvcApplication.Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +18
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75